# Walk Cycle not looping in Pygame, '+=' only executing once

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a smash clone as practice with pygame. When my character moves, I want it to go through a walk cycle. The issue is that when the character is moving, it only shows image 2 of 2 in the walk cycle, instead of cycling through the whole thing.

I created a class called Player so I could load as many players as I want, and created two separate functions within for moving left and moving right. Here is my code for that:

```
class PLAYER(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
     def __init__(self, fighter):
          super().__init__()
          width = 40
          height = 110
          self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
          self.change_x = 0
          self.change_y = 0
          self.fighter = fighter

          if self.fighter == "Frozone":
               self.FaceLeft = pygame.image.load("FrozoneFaceLeft.png")
               self.WalkLeft = pygame.image.load("FrozoneWalkLeft1.png")

          self.LWalkCycle = [self.FaceLeft, self.WalkLeft]

          self.index = 0
          self.image = self.LWalkCycle[self.index]

     def go_left(self, x):
          self.index += 1
          self.rect.x += x
          self.image = self.LWalkCycle[self.index]
          if self.index >= len(self.LWalkCycle):
               self.index = 0
```

The 'Face left' sprite is also part of the walk cycle.

Here's the main function of the game

```
def main():
     pygame.init()
     screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1400, 750])
     player1 = PLAYER("Frozone")
     activePlayers = pygame.sprite.Group()
     activePlayers.add(player1)
     clock = pygame.time.Clock()

     while True:
          for event in pygame.event.get():
               if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
               elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                         player1.go_left(-3)

          activePlayers.update()
          activePlayers.draw(screen)
          clock.tick(10)
          pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

There's also a stop function that activates after the 'a' key goes up. It resets self.index to 0, and I know for sure that it works.

I figured out that self.index isn't increasing every time go_left() is executed. I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like `self.index` can ever be 0 at the time that it's used.

Think of it like this: you're incrementing it as soon as the method is entered, then using the incremented value. You reset it to 0 when it overflows, but then increment it as soon as the method is entered.

```
 # Index is 0 here
 self.index += 1  # Then incremented to 1

 self.image = self.LWalkCycle[self.index]  # Then the incremented value is used.

 if self.index >= len(self.LWalkCycle):
     self.index = 0
```

I see two solutions:

- Start `self.index` at -1 so that it's 0 when incremented (ugly, and not as sensical).
- Increment *after* using `self.index`.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I tried both solutions, and both fixed a secondary problem, but my code still doesn't seem to work. Instead of the character getting stuck on the second image in the walk cycle, it gets stuck on the first.

Comment: @user12799479 I'd have to see your new code. I walked through the logic in my head, and it should work. You can edit it into the question at the bottom.

Comment: Though your answer worked and fixed another problem with the code, it wasn't the only issue that stopped the walk cycle from playing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that may be a little cleaner...  You can use a `cycle` from `itertools` to manage the loop.  Or you can wrestle with the index yourself and have to deal with resetting it to -1, which I agree is a bit ugly.

```
import pygame
from itertools import cycle

class PLAYER(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
     def __init__(self, fighter):
          super().__init__()
          width = 40
          height = 110
          self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
          self.change_x = 0
          self.change_y = 0
          self.fighter = fighter

          if self.fighter == "Frozone":
               self.FaceLeft = pygame.image.load("fig1.png")
               self.WalkLeft = pygame.image.load("fig2.png")

          self.LWalkCycle = [self.FaceLeft, self.WalkLeft]
          # make a cycle of the possible indices...  in this case, it is just [0, 1]
          self.l_walk_index = cycle(range(len(self.LWalkCycle)))

          self.index = 0
          self.image = self.LWalkCycle[self.index]

     def go_left(self, x):
          idx = next(self.l_walk_index)  # increment in the cycle
          self.image = self.LWalkCycle[idx]
          self.rect.x += x
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that the function was only executed when the key was pressed, rather than checking if the key was pressed every frame elapsed.

I replaced this code:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            player1.go_left(-3)
```

with this:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_a]:
    player1.go_left(-3)
```

so that it checks if the key is pressed this loop regardless of if it was pressed last loop